# Display calendar system name in java

Tags: java, android

How can I display the name of calendar system being used in java? For example, the output should be "Gregorian calendar" if this is the default calendar system of the system.

Comment: The default calendar system is whatever you use when you build your app.  Can you give some context to this question?

Comment: Check this tutorial. you will get some information regarding this. http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-calendar.html

Comment: you can refer this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html

Comment: I am looking for java command which when executed gives the output as "Gregorian calendar" if this is the calendar being used by the system. It can display "Korean calendar" if that is the default in the system.